# kafka connect elasticsearch by confluent compatibility with elastic search 6.x and kafka 2.0 or 0.11 and above

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, compatibility, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka connect elasticsearch connector which is provided by Confluent to get data from kafka topics and dump into elastic search index.[using Kafka Connect](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch)

**Currently I am using kafka version : 0.9 and elastic version 6.2**

But I need to update my **kafka to 0.11 or 2.0.0 and elastic version to 6.4.2.**

Now I need to know whether this connector supports latest version of kafka and elasticsearch...?
Is there any compatibility issues..?

Comment: What is the compatible kafka-connect version for elasticsearch 6.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating ElasticSearch from 6.2 to 6.4.2 should be ok. Because this Connector is using rest API of ES. So, it should be compatible with ES from version 2.X to 6.X.

For Kafka Compatibility, you can check it at: https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html. If you want to upgrade Kafka to 2.0.0, you need to make sure your Confluent version should be 5.0.